# R: add some text to plotting area in pheatmap

Tags: r, plot, text, pheatmap

I just want to add a chunk of text inside the plotting area of a `pheatmap`.

Since the `pheatmap` function already wraps everything within it, I am having difficulty figuring this out.

In the MWE below, I just want to add `long_text` below the plot or, preferably, to the empty lower right corner (adjusting the plot area accordingly, with appropriate line breaks, and in italics if possible).

If it's too complicated, adding the text as a sub-title in smaller form (italics if possible) would also work...

```
mymat <- matrix(rexp(600, rate=.1), ncol=15)
colnames(mymat) <- paste("sample_", 1:15)
rownames(mymat) <- paste("gene", 1:dim(mymat)[1], sep="_")
pheatmap::pheatmap(mat                      = mymat,
                   border_color             = NA,
                   main                     = "title here",
                   filename                 = "test.pdf"
)
long_text <- "I want to place this text in the bottom right corner, with the appropriate line breaks"
```

[image: test]

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `grid.text` function from the grid package. In your case, run the following code:

```
pheatmap::pheatmap(mat = mymat,
               border_color = NA,
               main = "title here",
               filename = "test.pdf")
grid.text("Your text", x = x coordinate, y = y coordinate)
```

Hope it works!

Best regards